# Use AngularJS 2 Component like a function in the element attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

**Hi guys!**

I'm learning AngularJS 2 for a while now and now creating my own app based on Laravel 5 REST API. Anyway - that isn't very important atm.

What is important is that I want to provide the translation for the whole application and I found an issue that is hard to solve for me.

So - from the beginning... I'm created my **ResourcesService** that's translating the string:

```
getTranslation ( key: string, replace: Array<TranslationReplace> = null, locale: string = null, fallback: boolean = null ): Observable<Resource> {

    var params = "key=" + key +
        ( replace ? "&replace=" + JSON.stringify(replace) : '') +
        ( locale ? "&locale=" + locale : '') +
        ( fallback ? "&fallback=" + fallback : '');
    var headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'getTranslation', params, {headers: headers})
        .map(this.extractData)
        .startWith({ name: 'Loading...', value: 'Translating...' })
        .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

And I created a **TranslateComponent** that's providing the translation, here's the whole component:

```
import {Component, Input, Injectable, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChange} from "@angular/core";
import {ResourcesService} from "../services/resources.service";
import {TranslationReplace} from "../models/TranslationReplace";

@Component({
    selector: 'translate',
    template: `{{translation}}`
})

@Injectable()
export class TranslateComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() ref: string;
    @Input() replace: Array<TranslationReplace>;
    @Input() locale: string;
    @Input() fallback: boolean;

    private translation: string;
    constructor(private resourcesService: ResourcesService) {}

    ngOnInit() : void {
        this.getTranslation();
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {
        for (let propName in changes) {
            if(propName == 'replace') {
                this.getTranslation();
            }
        }
    }

    private getTranslation(): void {
        this.resourcesService.getTranslation(this.ref, this.replace, this.locale, this.fallback).forEach(translation => this.translation = translation.value );
    }
}
```

All is working just perfect and to call for the translation I have to simply call the selector like that:

```
<translate [ref]="'string.to_translate'"></translate>
```

But...

Now I'd like to use the translation in the attribute.

So I found the ugly way to achieve it by creating the reference of the translation and the call it in the attribute. But it's very nasty...

First of all I need to add this bit to my template:

```
<translate [ref]="'string.to_translate'" style="display:none;" #myStringTranslation></translate>
```

And next in my element call it and ask for the property by the reference:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input" #input="ngModel [placeholder]="myStringTranslation.translation">
```

And I really don't like the idea.

What I'm looking for is to call it somehow, I don't know... emit it? And make it looks better. Don't create extra elements.

So my question is:
**Can I do it better? Can I somehow call the translation directly from the attribute without the reference?**

** ----- UPDATE ----- **

Ok, I learn my lesson :) Thanks to **Meir** for showing me the right direction and also the Angular.io site for the tutorials.

So finally I added a **TranslateDirective** to my application:

```
import {Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChange, Renderer} from "@angular/core";
import {TranslationReplace} from "../models/TranslationReplace";
import {ResourcesService} from "../services/resources.service";

@Directive({
    selector: '[translate]'
})
export class TranslateDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input('translate') ref: string;
    @Input('translateReplace') replace: Array<TranslationReplace>;
    @Input('translateLocale') locale: string;
    @Input('translateFallback') fallback: boolean;
    @Input('translateAttr') attr: string;

    private translation: string;

    constructor(
        private elRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer,
        private resourcesService: ResourcesService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.getTranslation();
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}):void {
        for (let propName in changes) {
            if(propName == 'replace') {
                this.getTranslation();
            }
        }
    }

    private getTranslation(): void {
        if(this.attr)
            this.resourcesService.getTranslation(this.ref, this.replace, this.locale, this.fallback).forEach(translation =>
            {
                this.translation = translation.value;
                this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement,this.attr,this.translation);
            });
    }
}
```

And now can easily add the translations to the attributes like that:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input" #input="ngModel [translate]="'string.to_translate'" [translateAttr]="'placeholder'">
```

**Thanks for your help!!**

Comment: There's no 'AngularJS 2', the name applies to Angular 1.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it into an attribute directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'translate'
})
export class TranslateDirectiev {
  @Input() translate: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
       if(this.translate){
          var translatedText: string = translateSvc.translate(this.translate);
          this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', translatedText);
      }
  }

}
```

This is a simple example without the service injection. Also, for input fields you might need to have a different approach and update the value attribute and not the innerHtml

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html help me solve the issue. Many thanks, buddy!